# Trying to loop through header names in an array and get its column range but loop failing at 2nd itiration

Tags: vba, for-loop

I am tring to get the column range for each header name, then act on that range then clear that range and act on the next range gotten from the header name

```
What  AAA   Where  BBB  Why CCC  How
ZZZ   ZZZ   ZZZ    ZZZ  ZZZ ZZZ  ZZZ
ZZZ   ZZZ   ZZZ    ZZZ  ZZZ ZZZ  ZZZ
ZZZ   ZZZ   ZZZ    ZZZ  ZZZ ZZZ  ZZZ
ZZZ   ZZZ   ZZZ    ZZZ  ZZZ ZZZ  ZZZ
ZZZ   ZZZ   ZZZ    ZZZ  ZZZ ZZZ  ZZZ
ZZZ   ZZZ   ZZZ    ZZZ  ZZZ ZZZ  ZZZ
```

I can get it for the first loop J=0 I have:

```
arrData = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, CN(0)), ws.Cells(LR, CN(0))).Value
```

Becomes

```
arrData = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1)), ws.Cells(LR, 1)).Value
MsgBox arrData(1, CN(0)) = cell(1,1)= What
```

But For J=1 I get:

```
arrData = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, CN(1)), ws.Cells(LR, CN(1))).Value
```

Should Become

```
arrData = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 3)), ws.Cells(LR, 3)).Value
MsgBox arrData(1, 3) = cells(1,3)= Where
```

But I get
 `Subscript out of range` for `MsgBox arrData(1, CN(1)) = "Where"`

So I do not think I am getting the range for the loop right after the first iteration or the `Erase` maybe is not being appled properly?

Thanks

Edit: It was as simple as: `MsgBox arrData(1, CN(J))` to this `MsgBox arrData(1, 1)`

```
Sub RCFLB_n()

RCFLB "XXX", Array("What", "Where", "Why", "How")

End Sub

Sub RCFLB(shtName As String, HNarr As Variant)
Dim arrData() As Variant, arrReturnData() As Variant, CN As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long, LC As Long
Dim I As Long, J As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(shtName)

'CHTCN is a public Function to get Array of Column numbers coresponding to Header names
'So CN = Array(1,3,5,7)
 CN = CHTCN(shtName, HNarr)

With ws
     LR = .Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
End With

For J = 0 To UBound(CN)
Erase arrData
arrData = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, CN(J)), ws.Cells(LR, CN(J))).Value
   MsgBox arrData(1, 1)

'Stuff

Next J

'Stuff

End Sub
```

Comment: From your brief edit am I right in thinking this one is solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `MsgBox arrData(1, CN(J))` to `MsgBox arrData(1, 1)` solved the issue.